# React Native: iOS Simulator not connecting to bundler

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I recently purchased a new Macbook Pro (2018 15" model), and I am not able to run any react native apps with the iOS simulator.  I am able to run the application in Android emulators, and on phyiscal iOS devices, but the iOS simulators give the error "No bundle URL present."  This includes even brand new applications.

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG7BR.jpg

Some things I've tried, without success:

- Fresh install of Node, Watchman, React-Native-CLI
- sudo chown -R $USER ~/.babel.json
- sudo chown -R $USER ~/.expo
- Made sure all software was updated
- Erased all Content and Settings on iOS simulator

Comment: Maybe you can try to run metro bundler in a different port with react-native run-ios --port=8088 ?

Comment: @negative_zero Just tried that, no luck.

Comment: Ok, run bundler normally and see if you can access it from simulator's browser over localhost:8081. Maybe something blocks simulator to access it. Also check if you have index.js in your app's root directory. Even though I guess it's there since you can run it on real device.

Comment: @negative_zero, localhost:8081 doesn't work in the browser, but 127.0.0.1:8081 works.

Comment: run using xcode